# i386-elf-_g++ install ubuntu

Tags: kernel, bootloader

I am trying to write an OS kernel and I need a certain dependency for compiling the assembly to an bin. The dependency is i386-elf-_g++. I cannot find any resources for installing it on ubuntu online so I thought I would ask the internet.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can install  i386-elf-_g++?

Comment: I wonder what underscore (`_`) could mean in the compiler name. Could you provide a link to the documentation/README/whatever document which states such requirement?